# how to retrieve value from command line argument in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line-arguments

i have written two statements in shell script and are as follows :-

```
str=$'cd /home \n mkdir $1'
echo "$str"
```

And When i execute above script file then it shows following output :-

```
[root]# ./ScriptCheck.sh pravin
cd /home
mkdir $1
```

Where Output should be :->

```
cd /home
mkdir pravin
```

Comment: Single quotes do not provide the output for a shell variable. To get the exact variabale, you might wanna enclose that inside double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Variables are not expanded in strings using single-quotes (`'`).  Try with double-quotes (`"`) instead.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes for more details.

Comment: Note that with double quotes, though, `\n` will be treated as two literal characters, not a new line. Adding `-e` to the call to `echo` will cause `echo` to interpret the pair as a newline again, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
str=$'cd /home ; mkdir $1'
echo "$str"
```